# How do I specify the column to display in a dropdownlist?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a database table with a computed column. The computed column merges two names (first and last) into a single display name. In the code below, I want to specify the value of the computed column, named DisplayName. How do I do this? Thanks!

FYI, this is MVC Beta 4.

```
<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PdId, "Pd")
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.DropDownList("PdId", String.Empty)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PdId)
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a view model and a strongly typed view and DropDownListFor helper. Can't see your code, so here’s an untested psuedo:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public int PdId { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Names { get; set; } 
}
```

populate view model from controller

```
public ActionResult VIewName(?)
{
    var people =  // query    
    var model = new MyViewModel
    {
       PdId = people.nameId,
       FullNames = people.Select(x => new SelectListItem
        {
             Value = x.nameId.ToString(),
             Text = x.FirstName + " " + x.LastName
        })
    };
    return View(model);
}
```

In  view use the strongly typed DropDownListFor helper

```
@model MyViewModel

@Html.DropDownListFor(
    x => x. PdId,
    Model. FullNames
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PdId, "Pd")
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.PdId, Model.DisplayName)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PdId)
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as the column is an actual field, it should be an option when you connect to the database when you do a SELECT in the DDL with a DISTINCT.

If it is an aliased column, and is being reference with a computated column then just reference the computed column in your select statement on the C# side...